# How do I get the response payload of a REST service from the Message of an outgoing Interceptor?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, interceptor

I have written a interceptor in the outgoing chain in the `SEND` phase and I want to get the payload of the response of my **REST** service into a String variable. How can I achieve this?

Here is my interceptor

```
public class MyLoginOutInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

    public MyLoginOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint to the `OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);` I see that the payload is in the os but I don't know how to get it into a String.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the responsePayload you should have what you want.

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
       OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
       StringBuilder responsePayload = new StringBuilder();
       CachedOutputStream cos = (CachedOutputStream) os;
       try {
               cos.writeCacheTo(responsePayload);
       } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream" . Not sure why. Can you help ?

Comment: you should use java.io.OutputStream;

Comment: With big payloads is not possible to extract payload... The result is an empty String: any idea on how to manage this?